# Interpreting/comparing node.js heap dumps in Chrome dev tools

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I am currently analyzing a memory leak/excessive memory usage issue in a large node.js application. One of the things I tried is looking at the V8 heap before/after certain operations, using the `heapdump` node module and the comparison view in Chrome dev tools. Surprisingly, even without doing much at all in the application, there seem to be huge changes between consecutive heap dumps, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: heap snapshot comparison view]

The biggest entries in the `(string)` section are apparently the full source code of the app's node.js modules. I am reading from this output that between the two heap dump calls, all of the JS code in string form (presumably stored somewhere in node's module cache/require mechanism?) gets garbage collected and immediately loaded again. Is that interpretation correct?

And I guess the underlying question is: Am *I* doing something silly here (i.e. using these tools incorrectly), or is *the app* really behaving as badly as it seems?

In case it helps, this is the corresponding output from `--trace-gc --trace-gc-verbose` during a heap dump:

```
[3365]   202482 ms: Mark-sweep 142.5 (180.2) -> 113.9 (175.2) MB, 216 ms (+ 108 ms in 529 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.946777 ms) [HeapSnapshotGenerator::GenerateSnapshot] [GC in old space requested].
[3365] Memory allocator,   used: 179432 KB, available: 1319704 KB
[3365] New space,          used:      4 KB, available:  16379 KB, committed:  32768 KB
[3365] Old pointers,       used:  48953 KB, available:  19074 KB, committed:  68031 KB
[3365] Old data space,     used:  44059 KB, available:   3745 KB, committed:  48564 KB
[3365] Code space,         used:  13451 KB, available:    292 KB, committed:  13944 KB
[3365] Map space,          used:   6577 KB, available:   1612 KB, committed:   8190 KB
[3365] Cell space,         used:    301 KB, available:    834 KB, committed:   1135 KB
[3365] Large object space, used:   3249 KB, available: 1318663 KB, committed:   3281 KB
[3365] All spaces,         used: 116597 KB, available:  41938 KB, committed: 175914 KB
[3365] Total time spent in GC  : 586 ms
[3365]   202637 ms: Mark-sweep 113.9 (175.2) -> 113.7 (167.2) MB, 152 ms [HeapSnapshotGenerator::GenerateSnapshot] [GC in old space requested].
[3365] Memory allocator,   used: 171240 KB, available: 1327896 KB
[3365] New space,          used:      0 KB, available:  16384 KB, committed:  32768 KB
[3365] Old pointers,       used:  48841 KB, available:  13142 KB, committed:  61984 KB
[3365] Old data space,     used:  44028 KB, available:   2226 KB, committed:  46548 KB
[3365] Code space,         used:  13388 KB, available:    555 KB, committed:  13944 KB
[3365] Map space,          used:   6577 KB, available:   1612 KB, committed:   8190 KB
[3365] Cell space,         used:    301 KB, available:    834 KB, committed:   1135 KB
[3365] Large object space, used:   3249 KB, available: 1326855 KB, committed:   3281 KB
[3365] All spaces,         used: 116386 KB, available:  34755 KB, committed: 167852 KB
[3365] Total time spent in GC  : 738 ms
```

Comment: I think string means just that. Whatever string your program creates("Helloo"). It is not the source code, unless you have lot of strings hardcoded. It looks very normal. You free 1 MB string heap in a second. There is nothing alarming here. If you think it is leaking memory take more dumps.

Comment: No, the bigger objects under `(string)` are definitely JS code (one object per module file, with matching size). Which I **think** is normal -- but continuously garbage-collecting and reloading them (I've looked at several consecutive dumps) seems very odd.

Comment: I've seen this too. It is pretty clearly module instances wrapped in the function providing __filename, __dirname, etc. They seem to be a lot add and a lot removed when comparing heapdumps so it looks like a transient population. I'd still love to understand why they are being created and deleted